# Ubuntu Mutual TLS failing Asp.net Core and also NodeJs

Tags: node.js, asp.net-core, client-certificates, mtls

I trying to implement a REST API with mutual TLS authentication following this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-7.0

I create a Root CA myCA.crt and then signed a child certificate with it (client.crt, then exported as clent.pfx), I did install the myCA.crt on my windows machine

This is hosting directly in kestrel, not proxy. Debuging in my dev machine (windows) the certificate authentication works, but when deployed to ubuntu, I get this error when making a request in my client code:

```
var clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2("client.pfx", "****"); 

var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCertificate);
var client = new HttpClient(handler);
var result = client.GetAsync("https://yyyyy.com").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

{"An error occurred while sending the request."}
InnerException  {"**The response ended prematurely.**"} System.Exception {System.IO.IOException}

In Ubuntu I have installed the ca certificate with this commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y ca-certificates
$ sudo cp myCA.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
$ sudo update-ca-certificates
```

and all looks good.

In Server site I have this program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Certificate;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Claims;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(
        CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCertificate(options =>
    {
        options.AllowedCertificateTypes = CertificateTypes.All;
        options.Events = new CertificateAuthenticationEvents
        {
            OnCertificateValidated = context =>
            {
                var claims = new[]
                {
                    new Claim(
                        ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,
                        context.ClientCertificate.Subject,
                        ClaimValueTypes.String, context.Options.ClaimsIssuer),
                    new Claim(
                        ClaimTypes.Name,
                        context.ClientCertificate.Subject,
                        ClaimValueTypes.String, context.Options.ClaimsIssuer)
                };

                context.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(
                    new ClaimsIdentity(claims, context.Scheme.Name));
                context.Success();

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });


builder.Services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(options =>
        options.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.RequireCertificate);
});


builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options => {
    var port = 443;
    var pfxFilePath = @"/etc/nginx/certs/cert.pfx";
    var pfxPassword = "****";

    options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, port, listenOptions => {
        listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1;
        listenOptions.UseHttps(pfxFilePath, pfxPassword);
    });
});



var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

If I remove this

```
builder.Services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(options =>
        options.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.RequireCertificate);
});
```

then the site shows the lock (cert.pfx is good) and I can navigate but not authentication info available.  If this is set, then browser ask for certificate, but always return an error when selecting a certificate. Postman retuns **Error: socket hang up**.

I was wondering if I miss something, then I tried to do it with node js, with the following code just for testing:

```
var msg = 'Hello World';
console.log(msg);
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');

https
  .createServer(
    {
      // ...
      cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/nginx/certs/cert.crt'),
      key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/nginx/certs/cert.rsa'),
      // ...

      requestCert: true,
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
      ca: fs.readFileSync('myCA.crt'),
    },
    (req, res) => {
      const ct = req.connection.getPeerCertificate();
      if (req.client.authorized) {
            res.writeHead(200);
            return res.end('Autenticado');
          } else if (ct.subject) {
                res.writeHead(403);
                   res.end(`Sorry ${ct.subject.CN}, certificates from ${ct.issuer.CN} are not welcome here.`)           }else {
          res.writeHead(401);
          res.end('No autenticado');
}
    }
  )
  .listen(443);
```

This time accesing to the site was getting a response, but this was because this setting: ** rejectUnauthorized: false. ** After I set this to true, then I started getting the same error when using Asp.net Core: **The response ended prematurely.**

When rejectUnauthorized =false, I get to the 403 error branch if I send a certificate and get to 401 error if I send the request without client certificate, but never the user is authorized.

[EDIT]
I verify my client.pfx (client.crt) agaist myCA.crt (myCA.pem) by ejecuting this on openssl:

```
openssl verify -verbose -CAfile myCA.pem client.crt
client.crt: OK
```

Any Ideas what could be wrong?